# grails spring security login is not working

Tags: grails, spring-security, passwords, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.1.0. I have installed spring-security-core plugin.

When I create user it is creating it. But when I try to login then it shows:

`"Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password."`

And there is also another fact that is when I use the same password for different user it does not save password with similar encoded value like for user 1 I have used password `123` which is saved in database like this

`d535ce213a0e8e4f9e724af47c46eea409ef401c03617b749da618a82890d743`

and for user 2 I also used password `123` and this time it is saved like this

`0849ea79a2c1bca057ded06c3053fb5bc5d7ba52b50982e73e44894d4f3e0aa6`

I don't understand. Can anyone please help me on this ?

my config.groovy >>>

```
    // locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
// config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
// in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }

grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination
grails.mime.file.extensions = true // enables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format
grails.mime.use.accept.header = false
grails.mime.types = [
    all:           '*/*',
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']

// The default codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// enable Sitemesh preprocessing of GSP pages
grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// configure auto-caching of queries by default (if false you can cache individual queries with 'cache: true')
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'common.auth.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'common.auth.UserAuthority'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'common.auth.Authority'
```

my login controller >>>

```
    import grails.converters.JSON

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

class LoginController {

    /**
     * Dependency injection for the authenticationTrustResolver.
     */
    def authenticationTrustResolver

    /**
     * Dependency injection for the springSecurityService.
     */
    def springSecurityService

    /**
     * Default action; redirects to 'defaultTargetUrl' if logged in, /login/auth otherwise.
     */
    def index = {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        } else {
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the login page.
     */
    def auth = {

        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        String view = 'auth'
        String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"
        render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
    }

    /**
     * The redirect action for Ajax requests.
     */
    def authAjax = {
        response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
        response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
    }

    /**
     * Show denied page.
     */
    def denied = {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() &&
                authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(SCH.context?.authentication)) {
            // have cookie but the page is guarded with IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
            redirect action: 'full', params: params
        }
    }

    /**
     * Login page for users with a remember-me cookie but accessing a IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY page.
     */
    def full = {
        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        render view: 'auth', params: params,
                model: [hasCookie: authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(SCH.context?.authentication),
                        postUrl: "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"]
    }

    /**
     * Callback after a failed login. Redirects to the auth page with a warning message.
     */
    def authfail = {

        def username = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]
        String msg = ''
        def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
        if (exception) {
            if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
            } else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
            } else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.disabled")
            } else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.locked")
            } else {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.fail")
            }
        }

        if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
            render([error: msg] as JSON)
        } else {
            flash.message = msg
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Ajax success redirect url.
     */
    def ajaxSuccess = {
        render([success: true, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name] as JSON)
    }

    /**
     * The Ajax denied redirect url.
     */
    def ajaxDenied = {
        render([error: 'access denied'] as JSON)
    }
}
```

my authority.groovy >>>

```
    package common.auth

class Authority {

    String authority

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

my user domain.groovy where my user will be saved >>>

```
    package common.auth

class User {

    transient springSecurityService
    String realname
    String username
    String password
    String designation
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        UserAuthority.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.authority } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

my userauthority.groovy >>>

```
    package common.auth

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class UserAuthority implements Serializable {

    User user
    Authority authority

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof UserAuthority)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.authority?.id == authority?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (user) builder.append(user.id)
        if (authority) builder.append(authority.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserAuthority get(long userId, long authorityId) {
        find 'from UserAuthority where user.id=:userId and authority.id=:authorityId',
            [userId: userId, authorityId: authorityId]
    }

    static UserAuthority create(User user, Authority authority, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserAuthority(user: user, authority: authority).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User user, Authority authority, boolean flush = false) {
        UserAuthority instance = UserAuthority.findByUserAndAuthority(user, authority)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(User user) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserAuthority WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
    }

    static void removeAll(Authority authority) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserAuthority WHERE authority=:authority', [authority: authority]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['authority', 'user']
        version false
    }
}
```

And my createUser action to create user in AdministratorActionController >>>

```
    package administrator

import common.auth.User

class AdmistratorActionController {

    def springSecurityService

    def index() {
           redirect(controller: 'admistratorAction', action: 'createUser')
    }

    def createUser = {
                User user = new User(params)
                def password = user.password
                def salt = user.username //depends on what you're using as a salt
                user.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, salt)
                user.save()
                flash.message = "User Create Successfully !!!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are encoding your password twice, you already have encode() on beforeInsert in the domain, I think you need not to encode it again.

Comment: change the line
user.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, salt) to user.password=password
and then check
user.save(failOnError:true)

Comment: AdmistratorActionController -> createUser action, you have user.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, salt), which is encoding your password, even you have encodePassword on the beforeInsert in the User domain class
I think try with 
user.password = password
and then save user object

Comment: It's double-encoding, but that's not the correct fix since there's a salt being used. Just set the password as a property in the controller (remove the call to `springSecurityService.encodePassword()`) and change `springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)` to `springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, username)` in the domain class `encodePassword` method.

Comment: Yep I think You can go with Burt's fix
:)

Comment: @SaurabhDixit First of all I am so sorry for this delay. I was so busy on other work that's why I could not reply.It works in your way. But I have also tried Burt's way. It did not work. Now I need to know that is using salt is so important? and why did not Burt's way worked?

Comment: Adding salt will increase security a bit, salt will just add something to the password and then encode it, so its up to you, to use salt or not.
But you should use encodePassword() in only one place not on both.
as in your code in the controller:
you have salt=user.username
which will set username as a string and you send it as second parameter in the encodePassword, and same suggested by Burt to do it in the domain instead of controller, and set password as a normal property in the controller.
which will avoid double encoding.
:) Not so sure but hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security use hash of user password + a salt. Salt is used to defeat pre-computed rainbow table attacks that could otherwise be used to greatly improve the efficiency of cracking the hashed password database. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

For example, if we're using `username` as a hash, real value in database will be:

```
md5(user.password + '|' + user.username)
```

So for two different userw with same password:

- user: username: 'user1', password: 123
- user: username: 'user2', password: 123

you'll get two different values in database:

- `md5('user1|123')` == `975204d0650cc642730866d56f66b6fb`
- `md5('user2|123')` == `aa12022115555842a7f80564940ae49d`

So, if hacker have access to you database he cannot guess the password.

Spring Security uses same hashing function and salt for saving and loading user. And if it unable to find user it probably means that you've used different salt for initial save and for later load from the database. Make sure that you have same salt source, and it's not changing (like `id` field, that have `null` value when you just creating a new user)

Comment: I have add user after install spring-security. I am new to grails and so far I can think spring-security will not let save a user with null value. Actually I don't know. I am giving my source code so that you could help me. It will be so appreciated.